# hadoop map task restart when reduce complete 80%

Tags: hadoop

I'm running hadoop on 2.2.0 on a cluster about 50 nodes, my job is 64 map tasks and 20 reduce tasks.The map complete in about 30 minutes, then all the reduce tasks running, but I found a strange log like this:

```
    14/10/08 21:41:04 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 37% reduce 10%
    14/10/08 21:41:05 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 38% reduce 11%
    14/10/08 21:41:07 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 39% reduce 12%
    14/10/08 21:41:08 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 40% reduce 12%
    14/10/08 21:41:09 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 41% reduce 12%
    14/10/08 21:41:10 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 42% reduce 12%
    14/10/08 21:41:12 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 44% reduce 12%
    14/10/08 21:41:14 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 45% reduce 12%
    14/10/08 21:41:16 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 46% reduce 13%
    14/10/08 21:41:18 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 48% reduce 13%
    14/10/08 21:41:21 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 49% reduce 13%
    14/10/08 21:41:22 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 13%
    14/10/08 21:41:25 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 51% reduce 14%
    14/10/08 21:41:29 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 52% reduce 15%
    14/10/08 21:41:34 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 52% reduce 16%
    14/10/08 21:41:38 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 53% reduce 17%
    14/10/08 21:41:53 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 53% reduce 18%
    14/10/08 21:42:09 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 54% reduce 18%
    14/10/08 21:42:18 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 55% reduce 18%
    14/10/08 21:42:37 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 56% reduce 18%
    14/10/08 21:42:49 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 56% reduce 19%
    14/10/08 21:42:53 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 57% reduce 19%
    14/10/08 21:42:57 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 58% reduce 19%
    14/10/08 21:42:59 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 59% reduce 19%
    14/10/08 21:43:00 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 60% reduce 19%
    14/10/08 21:43:05 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 61% reduce 19%
    14/10/08 21:43:06 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 62% reduce 19%
    14/10/08 21:43:09 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 62% reduce 20%
    14/10/08 21:43:13 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 63% reduce 20%
    14/10/08 21:43:16 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 63% reduce 21%
    14/10/08 21:43:19 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 64% reduce 21%
    14/10/08 21:43:36 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 65% reduce 21%
    14/10/08 21:43:42 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 66% reduce 21%
    14/10/08 21:43:44 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 67% reduce 22%
    14/10/08 21:44:00 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 68% reduce 22%
    14/10/08 21:44:09 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 70% reduce 22%
    14/10/08 21:44:12 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 70% reduce 23%
    14/10/08 21:44:18 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 71% reduce 23%
    14/10/08 21:44:24 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 72% reduce 23%
    14/10/08 21:44:28 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 72% reduce 24%
    14/10/08 21:44:35 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 73% reduce 24%
    14/10/08 21:44:44 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 74% reduce 24%
    14/10/08 21:44:50 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 75% reduce 24%
    14/10/08 21:44:51 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 76% reduce 24%
    14/10/08 21:44:54 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 77% reduce 25%
    14/10/08 21:45:00 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 78% reduce 25%
    14/10/08 21:45:07 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 78% reduce 26%
    14/10/08 21:45:15 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 79% reduce 26%
    14/10/08 21:45:17 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 80% reduce 26%
    14/10/08 21:45:20 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 81% reduce 26%
    14/10/08 21:45:24 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 82% reduce 26%
    14/10/08 21:45:27 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 83% reduce 26%
    14/10/08 21:45:29 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 83% reduce 27%
    14/10/08 21:45:34 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 85% reduce 27%
    14/10/08 21:45:37 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 86% reduce 27%
    14/10/08 21:45:42 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 86% reduce 28%
    14/10/08 21:45:43 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 88% reduce 28%
    14/10/08 21:45:45 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 89% reduce 28%
    14/10/08 21:45:47 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 89% reduce 29%
    14/10/08 21:45:56 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 89% reduce 30%
    14/10/08 21:45:58 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 90% reduce 30%
    14/10/08 21:46:00 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 91% reduce 30%
    14/10/08 21:46:06 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 92% reduce 30%
    14/10/08 21:46:10 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 92% reduce 31%
    14/10/08 21:46:12 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 93% reduce 31%
    14/10/08 21:46:24 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 94% reduce 31%
    14/10/08 21:48:02 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 95% reduce 31%
    14/10/08 21:48:12 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 95% reduce 32%
    14/10/08 21:48:13 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 96% reduce 32%
    14/10/08 21:48:22 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 97% reduce 32%
    14/10/08 21:49:00 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 98% reduce 32%
    14/10/08 21:49:09 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 98% reduce 33%
    14/10/08 21:49:19 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 99% reduce 33%
    14/10/08 21:49:22 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 33%
    14/10/08 21:49:27 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 34%
    14/10/08 21:49:28 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 37%
    14/10/08 21:49:29 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 40%
    14/10/08 21:49:30 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 42%
    14/10/08 21:49:32 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 44%
    14/10/08 21:49:33 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 46%
    14/10/08 21:49:34 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 48%
    14/10/08 21:49:35 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 49%
    14/10/08 21:49:36 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 54%
    14/10/08 21:49:37 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 55%
    14/10/08 21:49:39 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 58%
    14/10/08 21:49:40 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 59%
    14/10/08 21:49:41 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 60%
    14/10/08 21:49:42 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 61%
    14/10/08 21:49:44 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 62%
    14/10/08 21:49:46 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 63%
    14/10/08 21:49:48 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 64%
    14/10/08 21:49:50 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 65%
    14/10/08 21:49:56 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 66%
    14/10/08 21:50:03 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 67%
    14/10/08 21:52:11 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 68%
    14/10/08 21:56:12 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 69%
    14/10/08 22:00:35 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 71%
    14/10/08 22:00:40 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 72%
    14/10/08 22:00:55 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 74%
    14/10/08 22:01:09 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 75%
    14/10/08 22:01:14 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 77%
    14/10/08 22:02:23 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 78%
    14/10/08 22:02:37 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 80%
    14/10/08 22:03:32 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 82%
    14/10/08 22:04:14 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 83%
    14/10/08 22:04:43 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 85%
    14/10/08 22:08:11 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 86%
    14/10/08 22:08:45 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 88%
    14/10/08 22:09:53 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 89%
    14/10/08 22:11:21 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 91%
    14/10/08 22:11:44 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 92%
    14/10/08 22:13:23 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 94%
    14/10/08 22:13:25 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 95%
    14/10/08 22:15:21 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 97%
    14/10/08 22:18:14 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 97% reduce 98%
    14/10/08 22:18:15 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 97% reduce 100%
    14/10/08 22:19:14 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 97% reduce 95%
    14/10/08 22:19:15 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 97% reduce 90%
    14/10/08 22:19:27 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 97% reduce 91%
    14/10/08 22:19:35 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 97% reduce 92%
    14/10/08 22:20:36 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 97% reduce 93%
    14/10/08 22:34:55 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 94% reduce 93%
    14/10/08 22:35:20 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 95% reduce 93%
    14/10/08 22:40:46 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 96% reduce 93%
    14/10/08 22:40:55 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 97% reduce 93%
    14/10/08 22:40:59 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 97% reduce 94%
    14/10/08 22:41:12 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 97% reduce 95%
    14/10/08 22:51:43 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 98% reduce 95%
    14/10/08 22:52:52 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 99% reduce 95%
    14/10/08 22:53:01 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 95%
    14/10/08 22:53:03 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 96%
    14/10/08 22:53:28 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 97%
    14/10/08 22:57:19 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 98%
    14/10/08 23:09:55 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
    14/10/08 23:10:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1412772687841_0019 completed successfully
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if one your Node dies in between the job.

For example a Task tracker is doing a task and its 50% complete. It updates the Job Tracker the same through heart beat. Then if that node dies, the progress is lost and the job will have to be restarted. This might cause the overall % of completion to reduce.

Comment: Indeed. I do not think this is a critical problem at all. I too believe it is a simple node failure and restart.